# Is there an include directive for Kubernetes yaml resource definitions?

Tags: kubernetes

Consider the following `ConfigMap` definition, in, say, `foo.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: foo-data
data:
  foo.json: |-
    {
      "foo": "foo",
      "bar": 42
    }
```

Is there a way to load the `foo.json` data from an external file, instead of inlining it in the template? It would be nice if I could put the data in a file `foo.json` next to `foo.yml`, reference it somehow, and have K8s figure it out when I apply the template.

Is that possible? How?

If not, is the feature on the roadmap?

Comment: Maybe [helm](https://helm.sh/) can help you out. It is a k8s package manager with templating capabilities.

Comment: There are tons of templating solutions, see for example https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-state-app-templating/

Comment: @fishi: I've looked at helm, but it's so far been too much magic for me (and I'm quite new to the k8s scene, so the combined terminology of helm + k8s was too much for me to tackle all at once). Should I take your comment as a "no" to "is it possible?"

Comment: So far I haven't heard about a k8s built-in templating solution and I am not sure if there is one on the roadmap.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no build-in templating as for now but you can use ansible templating capabilities with k8s yaml files saute or together with e.g. k8s plugin.

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen only one in-cluster templating tool:

https://github.com/kelseyhightower/konfd

However, it does not do what the question is asking for.

Generally speaking the tooling world seems mostly focused on doing resource template rendering out of cluster, probably to reduce complexity when it comes to resource lifecycle.

Maybe the thing to do is write a simple shell script to take a json file and spit out a ConfigMap "wrapper" for it, which can then be piped to kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configmap from a file:

```
kubectl create configmap foo-data --from-file=foo.json
```

See details in the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

h/t https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991357/1017361