# How to dynamically populate values into Kubernetes yaml files

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to pass in some of the values in kubernetes yaml files during runtime like reading from config/properties file.

what is the best way to do that?

In the below example, I do not want to hardcode the port value, instead read the port number from config file.

Ex:

```
logstash.yaml
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
name: test
namespace: test
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
app: test
template:
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: logstash
    ports:
    - containerPort: 33044 (looking to read this port from config file)
    env:
    - name: INPUT_PORT
      value: "5044"

config.yaml

logstash_port: 33044
```

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a perfect use case for Helm (www.helm.sh).

Helm Charts helps you define, install, and upgrade Kubernetes applications. You can use a pre-defined chart (like Nginx, etc) or create your own chart.

Charts are structured like:

```
mychart/
  Chart.yaml
  values.yaml
  charts/
  templates/
  ...
```

In the templates folder, you can include your ReplicationController files (and any others). In the `values.yaml` file you can specify any variables you wish to share amongst the templates (like port numbers, file paths, etc).

The values file can be as simple or complex as you require. An example of a values file:

```
myTestService:
  containerPort: 33044
  image: "logstash"
```

You can then reference these values in your template file using:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
name: test
namespace: test
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
app: test
template:
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: logstash
    ports:
    - containerPort: {{ .Values.myTestService.containerPort }}
    env:
    - name: INPUT_PORT
      value: "5044"
```

Once finished you can compile into Helm chart using `helm package mychart`. To deploy to your Kubernetes cluster you can use `helm install mychart-VERSION.tgz`. That will then deploy your chart to the cluster. The version number is set within the `Chart.yaml` file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Kubernetes `ConfigMaps` for this. ConfigMaps are introduced to include external configuration files such as property files.

First create a ConfigMap artifact out of your property like follows:

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=db.properties
```

Then in your Deployment yaml you can provide it as a volume binding or environment variables

Volume binding :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: test
    ports:
    - containerPort: 33044
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /etc/creds <mount path> 
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: my-config
```

Here under `mountPath` you need to provide the location of your container where your property file should resides. And under`configMap` `name` you should define the name of your configMap you created.

Environment variables way :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: test
    ports:
    - containerPort: 33044
    env:
    - name: DB_PROPERTIES
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: my-config
          items:
          - key: <propert name>
            path: <path/to/property>
```

Here under the `configMapKeyRef` section under `name` you should define your config map name you created. e.g. my-config. Under the `items` you should define the key(s) of your property file and path to each of the key, Kubernetes will automatically resolve the value of the property internally.

You can find more about ConfigMap here.
https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/

Comment: The command should be kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=db.properties

Answer (score 0):

There are some parameters you can't change once a pod is created. `containerPort` is one of them.

You can add a new container to a pod though. And open a new port.

The parameters you CAN change, you can do it either by dynamically creating or modifying the original deployment (say with `sed`) and running `kubectl replace -f FILE` command, or through `kubectl edit DEPLOYMENT` command; which automatically applies the changes.